# How to iterate over a generator with indexes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

With arrays in javascript, getting the current index for iteration is easy. You can either use `forEach` and the index is the second entry, or use `for...of` and `.entries()` and array unpacking.

But generators have no `.entries()` method. How do I get the current index for a generator in my `for...of` loop?

I basically want:

```
function* myGen(){
    let i = 0;
    while(true) {
        i+=1;
        yield i;
    }
}

for(let [j, index] of myGen().entries()) { //<-- I want .entries() but for a Generator
    //...
}
//Running the above produces TypeError: myGen(...).entries(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not advisable to add things to a built-in prototype, but if you really want your code to work like that (calling `.entries()` on any generator), then you could proceed as follows:

```js
const Generator = Object.getPrototypeOf(function* () {});

Generator.prototype.entries = function * () {
    let i = 0;
    for (let value of this) {
        yield [i++, value];
    }
}

// Demo
function* myGen(){
    let i = 64;
    while(i < 70) {
        i+=1;
        yield String.fromCharCode(i);
    }
}

for(let [j, index] of myGen().entries()) { //<-- Now you have .entries() on a Generator
    console.log(j, index);
}
```

It is more prudent however to define a utility function.

```js
const GeneratorUtils = {
    * entriesOf(iter) {
        let i = 0;
        for (let value of iter) {
            yield [i++, value];
        }
    }
};

// Demo
function* myGen(){
    let i = 64;
    while(i < 70) {
        i+=1;
        yield String.fromCharCode(i);
    }
}

for(let [j, index] of GeneratorUtils.entriesOf(myGen())) {
    console.log(j, index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way to do it - the generator will have to *yield* something that contains the index. For example:

```js
function* myGen(){
  let index = 0;
    while(index < 10) {
      const item = 'foo' + index;
      yield { item, index };
      index++;
    }
}

for(const { item, index } of myGen()) {
  console.log('item: ' + item);
  console.log('index: ' + index);
}
```

If you can't modify a generator that you want to also get the index of, you can put it inside *another* generator that *does* keep track of the index (or you could just increment on every iteration outside):

```js
function* unmodifiableGen(){
  // index is private, is not being yielded
  let index = 0;
  while(index < 10) {
    yield Math.random();
    index++;
  }
}
function* generatorCounter(gen) {
  // this index *will* be yielded:
  let index = 0;
  for (const item of gen()) {
    yield { item, index };
    index++;
  }
}

for(const { item, index } of generatorCounter(unmodifiableGen)) {
  console.log('item: ' + item);
  console.log('index: ' + index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach might be to make `myGen()` a regular function that returns an object adhering to the iterator protocol rather than a generator. Then you can just give it an `entries()` method. It will work a little differently than a generator (you can't call `next()` on it directly). But it be self-contained and should work as expected in situations where an iterator is expected:

```js
function myGen(start, stop){
   return  {
        [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
            while(start < stop){
                yield start++
            }
        },
        entries: function* entries (){
            let i = 0
            for (n of this){
                yield [i++, n]
            }
        }
    }
}

 
let g = myGen(10, 20)
// works like a regular iterator:
console.log([...g])

// but you can also call entries():
g = myGen(2, 9)
for ([i, n] of g.entries()){
  console.log(`index: ${i}, value: ${n}`)
}
```

Comment: There's no good reason not to define `[Symbol.iterator]` with generator syntax as well…

Comment: That's a good point, thanks @Bergi — just too wrapped up in it to notice…edited.

Answer (score 1):

> But generators have no `.entries()` method. How do I get the current
>   index for a generator in my `for...of` loop?

You can utilize spread element preceding generator function call within an array literal and `.entries()` method of `Array.prototype`

```js
function* myGen() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10) {
    i += 1;
    yield i;
  }
}

for (const [index, value] of [...myGen()].entries()) {
  console.log(index, value);
}
```